# opening new webpage with window.open brings up dialog box

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using google pages to build a website, and am experiencing a problem I don't understand. I'm using window.open on a login form to bring up a new window utilizing google maps. The submit button opens a dialog box asking if I want to download or save the file. I hit open and it does bring up the page as expected. But the file is a downloaded file on my c drive. How do I eliminate the dialog box and get the html code to render automatically. Is this a browser issue or a coding issue? There is some web issue going on that I don't understand, and is probably very evident to someone who is an experienced web programmer. I would appreciate all thoughts and ideas.

Thanks

The window.open code is show below:

```
window.open('https://sites.google.com/site/mywebsite/mykmlfiles   
/agserver2.htm','_blank');
```

agserver2.htm is listed below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="MAP" /> 
  <Content type="html">

<![CDATA[

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/HTML; charset=UTF-8">

<title>AgServer</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples   
/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false& 
libraries=visualization"></script>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

var map;
var layers = [];

function initialize() {
  var montana = new google.maps.LatLng(46.0, -110.0);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: montana,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  layers[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://sites.google.com/site/mywebsite
  /mykmlfiles/soils.kml', {preserveViewport:true});

  layers[0].setMap(map);
}

function togglelayer(i) {
   if(layers[i].getMap() === null) {
      layers[i].setMap(map);
   }
   else {
      layers[i].setMap(null);
   }

</script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
   <div id ="toolbar" style="width: 100%; height:20px; text-align:center">
      <input type="button" value="Toggle Soils" onclick="togglelayer(0);"></input>
   </div>
   <div id="map_canvas" style="top:30px;"></div>
</body>
]]>
  </Content> 
</Module>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to set a MIME type for a file, so the browser doesn't try to download it. I'm just guessing it's a KML file.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to redirect, then use window.location("put address here")